# What was the first jet-powered supersonic aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history, jet, supersonic

Just to clarify: I am explicitly *not* referring to the [Bell X-1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_X-1), or any other early experimental supersonic aircraft that were rocket-powered. I'm curious as to the first supersonic aircraft powered by an *air-breathing* jet engine, as well as (if possible) the technological innovations needed to transition from rocket-powered to air-breathing supersonic flight.

Comment: in level flight? Or during a dive?

Comment: @rul30 I meant in level flight. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[One ME-262 Pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Guido_Mutke) claims to have exceeded Mach 1 in a dive, but the conditions are disputed due to compressibility and later tests that find the aircraft uncontrollable above Mach .84. The first U.S. fighter plane to exceed Mach 1 in level flight is the [F-100 Super Sabre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-100_Super_Sabre).

For research on how the sound barrier was broken as it results to aircraft design is to read [Wikipedia: Sound Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_barrier).

Wikipedia also has a good read on [Supersonic Aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_aircraft) that lists aircraft by manufacture date.

As for technological innovations, I would suggest reading about the [turbofan engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbofan), specifically [inlet design](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/inlet.html) since the air must be slowed sub-sonic before entering the compressor stages.

Comment: It appears, from your "Supersonic Aircraft" link that the F-100 was manufactured in 1953. The MiG-19 was also built in 1953, while the Saab 32 Lansen was manufactured in 1952, and the Convair XF-92 was built in 1948. Was the F-100 the first to attain stable Mach1+ level flight?

Comment: The F-100 is the first *American* aircraft to sustain Mach 1+, and as far as I can tell the first fighter to sustain it. The XF-92 was only able to hit Mach 1+ in a dive (and it was a 1-off prototype). The Saab 32 was in development in 1952 but not manufactured until 1955 (plus its top speed was Mach 1.031 on a good day). Really when you get down to it you are probably talking months between a few models so its difficult to nail down which one had it first.

Comment: Just wondering since you specifically called out the _first US fighter_, while the question asked for _first_. I'm good with your answer and explanation.

Comment: @FreeMan for other countries accurate data is often not available (especially the USSR and China come to mind). Dates for aircraft as to first flight, in service date, etc. are often guessed from when the aircraft is first seen and where by spy cameras rather than official documents.

Answer (score 3):

> A member of the Century Series, the F-102 was the USAF's first operational supersonic interceptor and delta-wing fighter. (Wikipedia: [Convair F-102 Delta Dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_F-102_Delta_Dagger))

Its innovative "[coke bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_rule)" fuselage design to lower the drag at the wing root was critical in achieving supersonic flight.

> [image: Me at Saigon with my F102]
> Me at Saigon with my F102

Answer (score 3):

While not capable of level-flight supersonic performance, the Korean War era F-86 Sabrejet was capable of slightly exceeding Mach 1 (I recall the figure as Mach 1.05) in a shallow dive.  This was one of its performance points over the (otherwise similar) MiG-15, which was Mach-limited and became nearly uncontrollable in the transonic regime.

While not generally considered "supersonic" the F-86 was capable of limited supersonic flight, and had several important features that were common to later truly supersonic designs -- sharply swept wings and fuselage-mounted drag brake panels, for example.

Comment: Legend has it breaking the sound barrier in a dive, unleashing a much louder boom than the climbing X-1 (the sane way to try it).

Answer (score 2):

DH108 (de Havilland) Powered by the 3000lb thrust DH Goblin and piloted by John Derry 6th Sept 1948 achieved Mach 1.07 in a dive.

According to an account published in "The Evening Star", Washington, DC (Sep 10, 1948), p. A-19:

[image: Article]

In 1948, the Royal Aero Club awarded John Derry the [Gold Medal](https://www.eacomms.co.uk/index.php/raecrecip/jd-derry) for being the first British subject to exceed the speed of sound.

For more information, see Brian Rivas and Annie Bullen, "John Derry: The Story of Britain's First Supersonic Pilot" (1982)

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE. Can you provide a link to this incident so that an interested reader can verify it & learn more about it?